# Построение изображения из массива точек в Windows 8 WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt

Есть проблема:
Имеется массив чисел и некая функция, которая задает цвет для точек.

Нужно нарисовать картинку закрашивая пиксели.
В `Windows Form` можно для этого можно было использовать класс `Bitmap`.

А как это реализовать в `WinRT`?

Либо подскажите библиотеку для работы с `Dicom` файлами, которая сможет достать изображение в "готовом" виде.

Comment: Попробуйте Canvas и прямоугольники на нём, или круги. WPF по сути векторный, использовать точечные пиксели в нём неправильно.

Comment: Кстати, класс [`Bitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) не WinForms-специфичен, вы вполне можете его использовать.

Comment: Разве Bitmap доступен в приложениях для Windows Store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать WritableBitmap, но в WinRT в нем отсутствует доступ к конкретным точкам, поэтому нужно это обходить [как в одном из принятых ответов здесь](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/39b3c702-caed-47e4-b7d3-b51d75cbca9b/).

А чтобы не танцевать с бубном самому, можно взять готовую [библиотеку, расширяющую WritebleBitmap,](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) и использовать методы из нее.

Comment: Использовал библиотечку WriteableBitmapEx - быстро и удобно.